# Trigger popover on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a form where I want to show a popover helpbox on hovering over the info div:
[image: Input]

The info div and the popover are as follows (parent div is `position: relative`):

```html
<div popovertarget="function-help" class="absolute cursor-help right-1 top-0 bottom-0 m-auto rounded-full border-2 border-cyan-400 text-cyan-400 w-1 h-1 p-2 flex justify-center items-center">i</div>
<div id="function-help" popover>Here's how to input a function:</div>
```

I know how to do it with a button or input, but how to do it with a div, and on hovering?

***How do I show the popover when the user hovers over the info div, and hide it when he leaves?***

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I recommend showing how you are actually implementing it via right now. You don't show how the popover is being triggered.

Comment: @imvain2 it's not being triggered. That's what I'm trying to accomplish. The code is as described in a fireship video, but it was with a button.

Comment: How is it being triggered via the button? No one can help you trigger it in another way without seeing how its being triggered now with a button

Comment: @JaideepShekhar are you trying to display tooltip on hovering?

Comment: @imvain2 literally how it is written, with the first div being a button. It's obvious.

Comment: @SaiManoj yes, yes I am.

Comment: @JaideepShekhar I have posted a snippet. Please check it

Answer (score 2):

As per my understanding you are trying to display a tooltip using `div` when user hovers on `i`. If that's the case you can use `EventListener` to show/hide div as per your requirement

```js
var targetElement = document.querySelector('.icon');
var tooltip = document.getElementById('tooltip');

targetElement.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
  tooltip.style.display = 'block';
});

targetElement.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
  tooltip.style.display = 'none';
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.container input {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.container .icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 5px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #39a9db;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: help;
}

.tooltip {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  z-index: 1;
  right: 0px;
  top: 25px
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <h3>f(x) = </h3>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <input type="text">
  <div class="icon">i</div>
  <div class="tooltip" id="tooltip">This is a tooltip</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok yes, I forgot you could use a `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` for a div. Thanks!

Comment: @JaideepShekhar if the helps, please accept the answer. Happing coding :)

Comment: I upvoted your answer, but I feel your answer is better as a general solution. In my specific case, I made it work with the Popover API. Also see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I realized my confusion. The Popover API is an experimental feature that doesn't have a wide browser compatibility.

My answer allows you to have multiple popovers on the same page.

It uses querySelectorAll to find all of the popovertarget elements. Then it loops through each generating a variable to hold the popover element. Then on mouseover it shows it and on mouseout it hides it.

Personally I would use a plugin that mimics the popover as it will have cross browser compatibility.

```js
const popover = document.querySelectorAll("[popovertarget]");

popover.forEach((e) => {
  const target = document.querySelector("#" + e.getAttribute("popovertarget"));
  e.addEventListener("mouseover",()=>{
    target.showPopover();
  });
  
  e.addEventListener("mouseout",()=>{
    target.hidePopover();
  });
});
```

```html
<div popovertarget="function-help">popME</div>
<div id="function-help" popover>Here's how to input a function:</div>
```

Comment: Nice answer. Is there any difference between using `mouseenter` vs `mouseover` and `mouseleave` vs `mouseout`? Also, most probably, a user would want to position that popover.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks to [@Sai Manoj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9380480/sai-manoj)'s helpful answer, I got that I could use the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` methods of a div to trigger the popover.

So here's my code:

```js
document.getElementById('info-tooltip').onmouseenter = _ => document.getElementById('function-help').showPopover()
document.getElementById('info-tooltip').onmouseleave = _ => document.getElementById('function-help').hidePopover()
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: max-content;
}
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10 rem;
}
#info-tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 4px;
  cursor: help;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 100px;
  border: 2px solid cyan;
  color: cyan;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
#function-help:popover-open {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  inset: unset;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <label for="inputFunction">f(x) = </label>
    <input type="text" id="inputFunction">
    <div id="info-tooltip" popovertarget="function-help">i</div>
    <div id="function-help" popover>Here's how to use this function:</div>
</div>
```

Note that you could further style the popover, but you would most probably want to use `position: absolute` (since default is `position: fixed`) and `inset: unset`.